# Memory ordering questions on given example?

Tags: rust, atomic, memory-barriers

I have questions about memory reorderings in this code

```rust
fn do_something_under_lock(
    is_locked: &AtomicBool,
    some_atomic_counter_1: &AtomicUsize,
    some_atomic_counter_2: &AtomicUsize,
) {
    read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_before_lock();
    read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_before_lock();
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);

    let mut succeeded_acquire;
    loop {
        succeeded_acquire = is_locked
            .compare_exchange(false, true, Ordering::Acquire, Ordering::Relaxed)
            .is_ok();

        if succeeded_acquire {
            read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_inside_lock();
            some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(2, Ordering::Relaxed);

            is_locked.store(false, Ordering::Release);
            break;
        }
    }

    read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_after_lock();
    read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_after_lock();
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
}
```

---

Here I will be giving a list of questions and answers based on my understanding, but I would like confirmation if I am correct:

1. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_before_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place before `do_something_under_lock` call(like if it was inlined)?

   > Yes, up until the point where we have atomic `Acquire`(because `Acquire` prevents reordering to places before itself) or non-atomic operation on same memory(because it would break single threaded logic)
2. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_before_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place after atomic `Acquire`?

   > Yes, because atomic `Acquire` doesn't prevent compiler from reordering to places after it
3. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_before_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place after

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_inside_lock();
   ```

   ?

   > No, because these operations affect same memory, so they should happen in same order, as they were met in code, because otherwise logic of single threaded execution may break
4. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_inside_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place after atomic `Release`?

   > No, because atomic `Release` prevents it
5. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_after_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place before `Release`?

   > Yes, because atomic `Release` doesn't prevent reordering to places before itself
6. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_after_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place before

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_inside_lock();
   ```

   ?

   > No, because these operations affect same memory, so they should happen in same order, as they were met in code, because otherwise logic of single threaded execution may break
7. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_before_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place before `do_something_under_lock` call(like if it was inlined)?

   > Yes, up until the point where we have atomic `Acquire`(because `Acquire` prevents reordering to places before itself) or non-atomic operation on same memory(because it would break single threaded logic)
8. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_before_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place before

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_before_lock();
   ```

   ?

   > Yes, because these operations don't affect same memory and don't have atomic `Acquire` or `Release` between them
9. Can

   ```rust
   read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_before_lock();
   ```

   be reordered to place after atomic `Acquire`?

   > Yes, because atomic `Acquire` doesn't prevent compiler from reordering to places after it
10. Can

    ```rust
    read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_before_lock();
    ```

    be reordered to place after atomic `Release`?

    > No, because atomic `Release` prevents it
11. Can

    ```rust
    read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_after_lock();
    ```

    be reordered to place before `Release`?

    > Yes, because atomic `Release` doesn't prevent reordering to places before itself
12. Can

    ```rust
    read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_2_after_lock();
    ```

    be reordered to place before `Acquire`?

    > No, because atomic `Acquire` prevents reordering to places before itself
13. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place before `do_something_under_lock` call(like if it was inlined)?

    > Yes, up until the point where we have atomic `Acquire`(because `Acquire` prevents reordering to places before itself) or operation on same atomic memory(because it would break single threaded logic)
14. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place after atomic `Acquire`?

    > Yes, because atomic `Acquire` doesn't prevent compiler from reordering to places after itself
15. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place after

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(2, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    ?

    > No, because these operations affect same memory, so they should happen in same order, as they were met in code, because otherwise logic of single threaded execution may break
16. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(2, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place after atomic `Release`?

    > No, because atomic `Release` prevents it
17. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place before `Release`?

    > Yes, because atomic `Release` doesn't prevent reordering to places before itself
18. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place before

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(2, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    ?

    > No, because these operations affect same memory, so they should happen in same order, as they were met in code, because otherwise logic of single threaded execution may break
19. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place before `do_something_under_lock` call(like if it was inlined)?

    > Yes, up until the point where we have atomic `Acquire`(because `Acquire` prevents reordering to places before itself) or operation on same atomic memory(because it would break single threaded logic)
20. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place before

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    ?

    > Yes, because these operations don't affect same memory and don't have atomic `Acquire` or `Release` between them
21. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place after atomic `Acquire`?

    > Yes, because atomic `Acquire` doesn't prevent compiler from reordering to places after itself
22. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place after atomic `Release`?

    > No, because atomic `Release` prevents it
23. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place before `Release`?

    > Yes, because atomic `Release` doesn't prevent reordering to places before itself
24. Can

    ```rust
    some_atomic_counter_2.fetch_add(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
    ```

    be reordered to place before `Acquire`?

    > No, because atomic `Acquire` prevents reordering to places before itself
25. What would happen if we changed `Acquire` to `Relaxed` in line

    ```rust
    succeeded_acquire = is_locked
        .compare_exchange(false, true, Ordering::Acquire, Ordering::Relaxed)
        .is_ok();
    ```

    ?

    > Compiler wouldn't tell CPU to load to local core cache actual memory changes from global memory and would work on potentially old memory, causing race in `read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_inside_lock();`
26. What would happen if we changed `Release` to `Relaxed` in line

    ```rust
    is_locked.store(false, Ordering::Release);
    ```

    ?

    > Compiler wouldn't tell CPU to push local memory changes from local core cache to global memory and other cores would work on potentially old memory, causing race in `read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_inside_lock();`

Comment: Twenty-six questions in one post is really too many.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, this simple at first glance code produces so many questions, and without answering all of them on same example answer may be not full, and I also provided answers with my understanding, so in best case it may be enough to confirm that my understanding is correct

Comment: I understand, but I think you need to cut down to a much smaller number.  I would be willing to take the time to go through and answer four or five such questions, maybe, at most.

Comment: @NateEldredge I hope that I have correct understanding of what is happening there and gave correct answers to my questions, so it may be enough to find errors and answer where I am wrong(will be strongly appreciated, since I am seeking confirmation  if I have correct understanding or fixing my understanding), or telling that all is good

Comment: @NateEldredge I will add bounty after question is eligible for bounty

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtlety in #3 and #6, involving multiple accesses to the same non-atomic object.

First, apparently [Rust does not yet have a defined memory model](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/memory-model.html), so it may be that these questions cannot be answered with complete authority.  However, my understanding is that for all intents and purposes, it matches the C++ memory model, which is not defined in terms of "reordering" at all, but in terms of abstract ordering constraints that allow you to deduce whether certain program behaviors are possible or not.  So in that sense, asking whether one access can be reordered with another is not formally a well-defined question.

Now, in #3 and #6, what is true is that *within the current thread*, the accesses to the various `non_atomic_memory` objects will be observed *as if in program order*.  For example, `read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_inside_lock()` will read the value that was written by `read_and_write_non_atomic_memory_1_before_lock()`.  In that sense, they cannot be reordered.

However, from the point of view of another thread, they *can* be reordered, or worse.  In fact, if any other thread is observing this variable concurrently with these accesses, the program has a data race and its entire behavior is undefined.  (And in Rust, it should actually be impossible for any other thread to do so, unless there is `unsafe` code in play to defeat the borrow checker.) So the compiler is under no obligation to generate actual memory loads and stores matching the accesses that your `read_and_write()` functions do, if it can get the same effect *within the current thread* in some other way.  For instance, the value written by the `before_lock()` write might never actually be stored to memory, but instead cached in a register which is then used by the `inside_lock()` read.  Or they could be scrambled up in some arbitrarily complicated fashion.

The value in memory doesn't have to be "correct" until such time as another thread could access the variable without causing a data race, which doesn't happen at any point within the code you posted.